# POST a request to the local server

Tags: c#, php, post, localhost

I really want to find out why an empty string is coming to the server, I can't figure out what's wrong
with the server, as you can see from the logs, the request comes, but empty

```
            using (var wb = new WebClient())
            {
                var data = new NameValueCollection();
                data["username"] = "myUser";
                data["password"] = "myPassword";
                var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
                string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
```

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    parse_str($data, $params);
    
    $username = $params['username'];
    $password = $params['password'];
    
    var_dump($username);
    var_dump($password);
}
else {
    http_response_code(405);
    echo "Это не POST";
}
?>
```

I've already tried everything, but I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried looking in $_POST? e.g. `$username = $_POST["username"];`

Comment: As with any HTTP requests - use some HTTP debugger (i.e. Fiddler) to see what request you code *actually* makes and make sure it matches to what you expect/get from a working variant of the code. When you obtained this info please [edit] this question with the details you found.

Comment: "as you can see from the logs" -- nope, you haven't posted any logs. What's the response body, what are the headers, what's the HTTP status code?

Comment: When using POST, no need for file_get_contents and parse_str. You can directly use $_POST.

Comment: `wb.UploadValues` most likely causes a `multipart/form-data` request, I am assuming? https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php: _"`php://input` is not available in POST requests with enctype="multipart/form-data" if enable_post_data_reading option is enabled."_ (And the latter is the option that decides whether $_POST/$_FILES will be populated based on the _parsed_ request body.)